# Refresh Leftlet Map by a drop down in angular2

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am new to Angular2 and Leaflet Map. I am trying to create a dropdown, which value change will refresh the Map to a new One. For example if the drop down value is London, it will show the Map position for london, and if I change the drop down value to New York, the map will re-position to New York.

side-nav.component.ts --> here my drop down code is there

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedGeo"  >
        <option value="" nonselected class="nonvalue">--Select--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let geoArea of geoAreas" value="{{geoArea.value}}">
            {{geoArea.value}}
        </option>
      </select>
```

side-nav.component.ts -->

```
geoAreas: Array<Object> =[] = [
{"id":"1","value":"New York"},
{"id":"2","value":"London"},
{"id":"3","value":"India"}
```

];

map.component.html

```
<div class="col-8">
    <div class="card">
        <div id="londonMap" style="height: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from "leaflet";
import { Map } from "leaflet";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-map',
    templateUrl: './map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
 })
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  public map: Map;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {

   this.londonMap = L.map("londonMap", {
     zoomControl: false,
      center: L.latLng(51.505, -0.09),
      zoom: 12,
      minZoom: 4,
      maxZoom: 19
  });

  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(this.londonMap);

  this.NYMap = L.map("NYMap", {
      zoomControl: false,
      center: L.latLng(42.736424, -75.762713),
      zoom: 7,
      minZoom: 4,
      maxZoom: 19
  });
   L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(NYMap);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where is your code to handle the select value change?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the map container, you could very simply request the current map to change its view, typically using [`setView`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-setview), [`panTo`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-panto) or even [`flyTo`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-flyto).

If you just switch the map container, and user has already moved / panned around the new map, he/she will just see the last position the new map has been moved to, instead of the initial position.

You will need to record the destination coordinates into your `select`, or at least retrieve them from some centralized variable (could be your `geoAreas`).

Here is an example with `flyTo` (plain JS): http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have one more issue in getting the map variable from map.component.ts in side-nav.component.ts. Thats why not able to use this settings.